# Direct linking to route (e.g., /articles/:articleid) returns plain JSON, skips AngularJS and DOM

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a multipage blog based on https://github.com/linnovate/mean. 
Right now when I go directly to a `/articles/:articleid` type url, all that I see is plain JSON (`{"title":"this is the title","_id":"12345","user":"me"}`) returned from my database. If I go to `/articles/:articleid` from my main page `/` -> clicking a link, the page parses fine since Angular and the DOM have already loaded from being at the main page, so Angular reads and parses the JSON that's returned.

Ideally, I want to be able to enter a direct URL to an article (e.g., `/articles/:articleid`) and have the server load the DOM and then have AngularJS return and parse the JSON. Or have some way for my server to load the html/css/etc. if it hasn't been already, before parsing the JSON (and thus avoiding plain json outputs).

Node routes:

```
var articles = require('../app/controllers/articles');
app.get('/articles', articles.all);
app.get('/articles/:articleId', articles.show);
app.param('articleId', articles.article); //This is called when I directly link to an article
```

Articles model code:

```
exports.article = function(req, res, next, id) {
   Article.load(id, function(err, article) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));

      console.log(req.headers['x-requested-with']);
      if ( req.headers["x-requested-with"] === "XMLHttpRequest" ) {
         console.log('sending jsonp' + req.article.title);
         res.jsonp(req.article);
      } else {
         console.log("sending page");
         res.render('index', {     //my default JADE skeleton page
            user: req.user ? JSON.stringify(req.user) : "null"
         });
      }

      //req.article = article;
      next();
   });
};

exports.show = function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.headers['x-requested-with']);
   if ( req.headers["x-requested-with"] === "XMLHttpRequest" ) {
      res.jsonp(req.article);
   } else {
      res.render('index', { //default page
         user: req.user ? JSON.stringify(req.user) : "null"
      });
   }
};
```

Angular route:

```
when('/articles/:articleId', {
  templateUrl: 'views/articles/view.html'
}).
```

The controller that handles the individual article is:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    Articles.get({
        articleId: $routeParams.articleId
    }, function(article) {
        $scope.article = article;
    });
    //$scope.htmlReady();
};
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I did some checking for the content type in the headers. I'm now able to discern whether it's a direct link or if it's coming from another page in the app, but I don't know how both render the template page (jade), start Angular, and supply JSON to it all in one go if it's a direct link.

My folder structure:
    public
      -- css
      -- img
      -- js
      -- lib
      -- views

My log output when I direct link (it seems to be using `/articles` as a base):

```
GET /articles/72119103c2e3a932b51e000201 304 619ms
GET /articles/css/blogstyle.css 404 134ms
GET /articles/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js 404 126ms
GET /articles/lib/jquery/jquery.js 404 136ms
GET /articles/lib/angular/angular.js 404 134ms
GET /articles/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js 404 136ms
GET /articles/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js 404 148ms
GET /articles/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 404 58ms
GET /articles/lib/angular-ui-utils/modules/route.js 404 67ms
```

Comment: by `naked json` do you mean seeing angular expressions from markup in page?...like `{{myScopeItem}}`

Comment: Nope, I mean getting naked json (because angular sends Get requests when I ask for a some /article/:arcticleid, which returns JSON to my page).

Comment: have no idea what `naked json` is then

Comment: e.g. {"title":"this is the title","_id":"12345","user":"me"}

Comment: what is content type header being sent? Not very node savvy but never had angular not parse json for me when sent from php

Comment: Content type is text/html.  I think the problem is not within Angular; it's that if I directly link to `/articles/:articleid` then Angular won't even be invoked/won't even have started, much less get a chance to parse it (which I know it does b/c normally when you navigate to my base `/` route, html/css/js will load and Angular parses JSON properly and fills it in my template.  
Directly go to `/article/:articleid` = only see JSON objects. No html,css,js,Angular is not started. Node seems to directly send `res.jsonp(req.article)`<br>

Go to `/`->click to `/:articleid` = works fine, html,css,js

Comment: definitely a problem sending wrong header, and/or, wrong content. Can try using http interceptor, should also throw some error handlers in

Comment: That was helpful, thanks! I think my main question now is regarding how I can force a load of the page + start Angular once I've determined it's a direct link.

Comment: direct link? Load a new page? Use normal url's in href...really  not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: 1.User types `/localhost/articles/:articleid` in URL.Node calls .article, sends json. User only sees json in browser (Angular doesn't get invoked somehow because the DOM doesnt get loaded)  After today's change, Node calls .article, sees that x-requested-with is undefined, and theoretically should render the DOM and Angular, and also send JSON so Angular can load it.       
2.User goes to `localhost/`, clicks a link to `/localhost/articles/:articleid`. Angular queries for article, Node sends Angular the JSON, then Angular data-binds into my page since the page is loaded and Angular is started.

Comment: have you configured `$routeprovider` in angular?... all sounds very wrong. Also if set $routeprovider is it in html5 mode so don't need hash in url? As for serving html...that should come on main page of app...after that would all be whatever templates various routes, ng-view, directives and includes need

Comment: node shouldn't know you change route in browser, other than deliver any data that controllers ask for

Comment: Yes, my Angular route above is within $routeprovider. Also $locationprovider is set for html5 mode and for hashbangs.  I agree that serving HTML should come on the main page of the app. However the problem I'm running into is when I go to another template page directly via URL, it skips over the main page HTML loading so it ends up only being the JSON output.

Comment: I agree that Node shouldn't know my route is changing, and that's the problem I'm running into. Node is only serving the JSON data, and when I directly go to `/articles/:articleid`, Node only sends the JSON and the page doesn't load, so Angular isn't started and can't parse the data.

Comment: appears you are using paths incorrectly, and/or haven't set `$routeProvider ` to configure paths. Go through tutorial on agular docs site...should help. If not html5 mode...paths should look like  `localhost/myApp#/article/id` and default would be `localhost/myApp#/`

Comment: I'll take a look into it, but pretty sure my `$routeProvider` is not the issue, because 1) works fine if I first go to my index page, and navigate around my site, and 2) AngularJS is completely skipped when I directly go to `/articles/:articleid` (and I don't want it to be skipped), which means that there's no chance for `$routeProvider` to be a problem. The problem lies with NodeJS first and foremost.

Comment: then href used to get there is incorrect?? , missing something. Have a path set in routes for `/articles/` and `/articles/ :id` ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the request content-type and return the complete angular page when it is content/html and JSON when it is jsonp request. This is for the route `/articles/:articleId`, of course.

Comment: Sorry, how would this work?  Do you mean an intermediate step during Node routing like `app.get('/articles', articles.checkRequestType, articles.all);` where checkRequestType would check if the calling page has Angular loaded which would mean only JSON would need to be returned, and if Angular hasn't been loaded on the calling page (direct link, for example) then content/html would be sent as well?

Comment: In regards to your answer, Alex, see my edits to the post above - I've incorporated you and Charlie's comments on content-type but still am wondering what you have in mind for 'return the complete angular page'.  Thanks.